# ls -td fails to identify any directories

Tags: shell-script, ssh, ls, quoting

I'm having a bit of a problem working on a shell script. One of the commands within the script is used to push a set of commands from a Jenkins host to MySQL database hosts to run backups "locally" to the MySQL databases.

The problem comes when exporting a variable for later use. Anonymized example:

```
ssh -q -o Batchmode=yes mysql@${host} \
"export variable=$(ls -td ${backup_path}/FULL/*/ | head -1); \
echo $variable"
```

The goal of the `ls -td` is to pull the latest written directory in the `${backup_path}/FULL` subdir.

The error I get when executing this particular command is

```
ls: cannot access ${backup_path}/FULL/*/: No such file or directory
```

The echo of `$incr_basedir` also returns a null output.

I have already attempted is to check for existence of a subdir and verified permissions in ${backup_path}/FULL, here is the output:

```
-bash-4.2$ pwd
${backup_path}/FULL
-bash-4.2$ ls -l
total 498
drwxr-x---. 28 mysql mysql   2019 May  3 16:53 2017-05-03_16-47-37
```

How should I proceed in approaching my goal?

Comment: You really shouldn't be parsing ls output:  http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: How might I obtain the "most recently written subdir" without ls? I can also guarantee filenames which will play nicely with ls in this system. @FCTW

Comment: You could try using find:  https://www.dwheeler.com/essays/filenames-in-shell.html#find  Although I'm not sure that will fix the originating issue...

Comment: If you use double quotes the variables will be expanded on the "local" side, before being passed to `ssh`.  Use single quotes to have them only get expanded on the remote side, though I'm not sure what you're trying to do with `export variable` when you never use it

Comment: I only took a snippit of the code, where I am running into issues. I'll see what switching the scope will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems were caused due to scoping, as Eric mentioned earlier.

I had many local variables being sent and pushed through the compound ssh instructions which were not listed, which required the usage of double quotes. Since I wanted the ls -td to execute remotely, I made an entirely new ssh command specifically to set this variable. Once the variable was set, I entered it like any other.

```
    export variable="$(ssh -q -o Batchmode=yes mysql@$host 'ls -td ${backup_dir}/FULL/*/ | head -1')"
```

The error no longer persists. My issue was, in fact, scoping where the local host did not have the same directory structure as the remote host.